# Homological stability for orthogonal groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology, orthogonal-groups

In Vogtmann's paper "Spherical posets and homological stability for $O_{n,n}$" it is shown that for all fields different than the field $F_2$ with two elements the homology groups of the orthogonal group $O_{n,n}$ stabilize. Is there a stability result over the field $F_2$ and also for other orthogonal groups?

Comment: Google "Homology stability for unitary groups" ... results are often proved in this generality. In the split case (i.e. for $\mathrm{O}_{n,n}$ in the orthogonal case), there is a wide class of rings for which stability is known (Mirzaii - Van der Kallen). In the general case (e.g. for $\mathrm{O}_{n,k}$ with $k$ fixed and $n\to \infty$), much less is known (but it holds e.g. for number fields, their completions, and some S-arithmetic rings). You can also read Djament's *Sur l'homologie des groupes unitaires à coefficients polynomiaux* and see references therein.

Comment: (I don't see why some users felt this question had to be put on hold. It is a natural question in this very degree of broadness.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this follows from Section 5.4 of [Randal-Williams--Wahl](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870817301986). See also Remark 1.3 of [Sprehn--Wahl](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2020-373-07/S0002-9947-2020-08030-1/).